# Shrinking wedge of circles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm  spending too much time thinking about this problem :

I need to show that the shrinking wedge of circles which is path connected, locally path connected ,doesn't have a simply connected covering space .

hatcher gives a condition for a space to be semi locally connected

it's about the induced injection between the fundamental group of a neighborhood  U and the fundamental group of our space (here we need the opposite of that) .

I've asked my doctor about it and he told me that I can't use it since our space is "locally path connected " and not semi locally  ..Can anyone help me prove that this  X : shrinking wedge of circles does't have a simply connected covering space ?

I supposed it had , then i took a loop in my space X ,I lifted it up to a loop in the simply connected covering space , this loop would be homotopic to the constant loop, my intuition is to project it down , and prove that since my space is not simply connected  this loop can't be trivial but I'm feeling there's something missing or wrong .. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suppose by "shrinking wedge of circles" you are referring to the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring) ?

Comment: Yes , hatcher call it this way , but as far as I know they are the same @JoeyBF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Theorem** : A topological space $X$ has a simply connected covering space if and only if $X$ is path connected, locally path connected and semi-locally simply connected.

We are interested in the "only if" part of the story. Let $(E, e_0) \stackrel{p}{\to} (X, x_0)$ be a based covering map. Pick a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ that is evenly covered by $p$. $U_i$ be one of the slices of $p^{-1}(U)$, and let $f : S^1 \to X$ be a loop in $U_i$. Since, $p$ is a homeomorphism from $U_i$ to $U$, the loop $f$ lifts to a loop $\tilde{f}$ based at $e_0$. $E$ is simply connected, so there is a path-homotopy taking $\tilde{f}$ to the zero loop at $e_0$. Pushing down this path-homotopy to $X$ via $p$ gives the desired contraction of $f$ to the zero loop at $x_0$.

In the Hawaiian earring, it has the subspace topology of $\Bbb R^2$, hence any, however small, open neighborhood of the wedge point contains one of the circles in the boquet. Thus it's not semi-locally simply connected, which contradicts the existence of simply connected covering spaces.

Comment: As for why the loop represented by one of the circles is null-homotopic in the Hawaiian earrning $H$: there is a retract $H \to S^1$, given by collapsing all the other circles.

Comment: edit: is **NOT** null-homotopic

Comment: Why this retraction implies that the loop is not null homotopic ? Is it because S1 is not semi locally simply connected ? @mikemiller

Comment: @Butterfly The retract $H \to S^1$ induces an injective map $\Bbb Z \cong \pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(H)$ at the level of fundamental groups, which contradicts the existence of a null-homotopy.

Comment: Thank you for your generous help @BalarkaSen